# ZfcUserLoginWidget on Home Page Throws Fatal error: Call to undefined method ZfcUser\Options\ModuleOptions::getEnableDefaultEntities()

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2, zfcuser

I am using Zend Framework 2, Bootstrap 3, ZFCUser, ZFCDoctrineORMUser and Doctrine in tandem.  I found that the ZfcUserLoginWidget can be called directly from my index.phtml.  However, when I do this, the following error is thrown:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method ZfcUser\Options\ModuleOptions::getEnableDefaultEntities()
```

referencing the following:

```
if ($options->getEnableDefaultEntities()) {
        $chain = $sm->get('doctrine.driver.orm_default');
        $chain->addDriver(new XmlDriver(__DIR__ . '/config/xml/zfcuserdoctrineorm'), 'ZfcUserDoctrineORM\Entity');
    }
```

The `require` section of `composer.json` is as follows:

```
"require" : {
"php" : ">=5.3.3",
"zendframework/zendframework" : "2.3.*",
"doctrine/doctrine-orm-module" : "0.7.*",
"zendframework/zend-developer-tools" : "dev-master",
"symfony/yaml" : "2.*",
"zf-commons/zfc-user-doctrine-orm" : ">=1.0.0",
"zf-commons/zfc-base" : ">=0.0.1"
},
```

What must be done to remedy this fatal error?
UPDATE:  After changing from dev-master to release, the error is still thrown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using master?
Please use the released versions. Find them here: https://github.com/ZF-Commons/ZfcUser/releases